# Saving array in multiple txt files depending on their content in Java

Tags: java, arrays, file, methods, save

Basically, i have main method that create multiple music album using:

```
Album[] tabA = {new Album ("AAAAA", 0, 1960, 60, 0, "maison", "BBBB", true),
                    new Album ("CCCCC", 1, 1961, 61, 0, "maison", "DDDD", true),
                    null,
                    new Album ("EEEEE", 2, 1962, 62, 1, "maison", "FFFF", false),
                    new Album ("GGGGG", 3, 1963, 63, 1, "maison", "HHHH", true),
                    null,
                    new Album ("IIIII", 4, 1964, 64, 0, "maison", "JJJJ", false),
                    new Album ("KKKKK", 5, 1970, 70, 1, "maison", "LLLL", true),
                    new Album ("MMMMM", 6, 1971, 71, 1, "maison", "NNNN", true) };
```

What i want now is to save those album in 2 separate txt file depending on the 5th info (the 0 or 1) in the following method

```
saveAlbums(tabA);//call for the method inside the main method


public static void saveAlbums ( Album[] tab){


}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Does the class `Album` override the `toString()` method? And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You have to iterate on the elements of the tab , and see the nature of the 5th element using the getter , to decide which txt file , like this :

```
public static void saveAlbums ( Album[] tab){
for(Album t : tab){
   if ( t.getyourelement() == 1 ) // save in your first txt file
   if ( t.getyourelement() == 0 ) // save in your second txt file
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you were asking, but here's the full detail.

```
private static saveAlbums(Album[] albums) {
    List<Album> zeroList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Album> oneList = new ArrayList<>()

    for (Album album : albums) {
        if (album != null) {
            if (album.getValueNumberFive() == 0) {
                zeroList.add(album);
            } else {
                oneList.add(album);
            }
        }
    }

    writeFile("Album-Zero.txt", zeroList);
    writeFile("Album-One.txt", oneList);
}

public static void writeFile(String filename, List<Album> albumList) {
    Writer output = null;
    File resultFile = new File(filename);
    try {
        output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(resultFile));
        for (Album album : albumList) {
            output.write(album.toString());
        }
        output.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new SystemException(e);
    } finally {
        safeClose(output);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `List`s should be declared `List<Album>`.

Comment: Good catch.  Like in the writeFile params.  Fixed.